# Issue with drop using _SelectedIndexChanged and the browser back button

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, selectedindexchanged

I am trying populate one dropdown based on the selection of another drop down using `selectedindexchanged`. The second selection takes the user to another page. This works but if the user hit back. The section is remembered and a reselection results in the user being sent to the previous choice. So its like I need to reset the index somehow if the user hits back.

```
protected void btnCommitteeKeywordSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddCommitteeCategory.Items.Clear();
    ddCommitteeList.Items.Clear();
    panSelectaCommittee.Controls.Clear();
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CommitteeKeywordSearch.Text) || CommitteeKeywordSearch.Text != "Select a committee")
    {
        Response.Redirect("/IPA/IPAStaging2016/About/Committees_keywordsearch.aspx?Code=" + CommitteeKeywordSearch.Text);
    }
}

protected void ddCommitteeCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ddCommitteeCategory.SelectedItem.Value))
    {
        //nothing
    }
}

protected void ddCommitteeList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ddCommitteeList.SelectedItem.Value) || CommitteeKeywordSearch.Text != "Select a committee")
    {
        Response.Redirect("/IPA/IPAStaging2016/Committees/Committee_Detail.aspx?Code=" + ddCommitteeList.SelectedItem.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry my orginal post went haywire.

Comment: Edit the post to get the code displayed correctly, and add some more information supporting your question. This helps us helping you. Also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks I was trying to fix or delete the question, it submitted when it should have entered a carriage return, but I was hitting some sort of time restriction. It should be fixed now.